# Invalid start of buffer (garbage pixel on LCD) ST7565

Tags: c, arm, stm32, microcontroller

This is my first post on stackoverflow, and please be kind :). Ok i have problem like here (garbage pixel on LCD, image of the letters is mirrored.) https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/issues/1187 My display have driver st7565, and this is my library

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"
#include "ST7565.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "spi.h"
#include "font.h"

#define ST7565_STARTBYTES 0
extern SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;

//extern void DelaymS(vu32 nTime);

//extern void DelayuS(vu32 nCount);
uint8_t is_reversed = 0;

// a handy reference to where the pages are on the screen
//const uint8_t pagemap[] = { 3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4 };
const uint8_t pagemap[] = { 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };

// a 5x7 font table
extern const uint8_t font[];
int pData;
// the memory buffer for the LCD
uint8_t st7565_buffer[1024] = {
 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};


// reduces how much is refreshed, which speeds it up!
// originally derived from Steve Evans/JCW's mod but cleaned up and
// optimized
#define enablePartialUpdate

#ifdef enablePartialUpdate
static uint8_t xUpdateMin, xUpdateMax, yUpdateMin, yUpdateMax;
#endif



static void ST7565_updateBoundingBox(uint8_t xmin, uint8_t ymin, uint8_t xmax, uint8_t ymax) {
#ifdef enablePartialUpdate
  if (xmin < xUpdateMin) xUpdateMin = xmin;
  if (xmax > xUpdateMax) xUpdateMax = xmax;
  if (ymin < yUpdateMin) yUpdateMin = ymin;
  if (ymax > yUpdateMax) yUpdateMax = ymax;
#endif
}

void ST7565_drawbitmap(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, const uint8_t *bitmap, uint8_t w, uint8_t h, uint8_t color) {
  uint8_t i, j;
  for (j=0; j<h; j++) {
    for (i=0; i<w; i++ ) {
      if (bitmap[i + (j/8) * w] & (1<<(j%8))) {
        ST7565_my_setpixel(x+i, y+j, color);
      }
    }
  }

  ST7565_updateBoundingBox(x, y, x+w, y+h);
}

void ST7565_drawstring(uint8_t x, uint8_t line, char *c) {
  while (c[0] != 0) {
    ST7565_drawchar(x, line, c[0]);
    c++;
    x += 6; // 6 pixels wide
    if (x + 6 >= LCDWIDTH) {
      x = 0;    // ran out of this line
      line++;
    }
    if (line >= (LCDHEIGHT/8))
      return;        // ran out of space :(
  }
}


void ST7565_drawstring_P(uint8_t x, uint8_t line, const char *str) {
  char c;
  while (1) {
    c = *str++;
    if (! c)
      return;
    ST7565_drawchar(x, line, c);
    x += 6; // 6 pixels wide
    if (x + 6 >= LCDWIDTH) {
      x = 0;    // ran out of this line
      line++;
    }
    if (line >= (LCDHEIGHT/8))
      return;        // ran out of space :(
  }
}

void  ST7565_drawchar(uint8_t x, uint8_t line, char c) {
  uint8_t i;
  for (i =0; i<5; i++ ) {
    st7565_buffer[x + (line*128) ] = font[((unsigned char)c * 5) + i];
    x++;
  }

  ST7565_updateBoundingBox(x-5, line*8, x-1, line*8 + 8);
}


// bresenham's algorithm - thx wikpedia
void ST7565_drawline(uint8_t x0, uint8_t y0, uint8_t x1, uint8_t y1,
              uint8_t color) {
  uint8_t steep = abs(y1 - y0) > abs(x1 - x0);
  if (steep) {
    swap(x0, y0);
    swap(x1, y1);
  }

  if (x0 > x1) {
    swap(x0, x1);
    swap(y0, y1);
  }

  // much faster to put the test here, since we've already sorted the points
  ST7565_updateBoundingBox(x0, y0, x1, y1);

  uint8_t dx, dy;
  dx = x1 - x0;
  dy = abs(y1 - y0);

  int8_t err = dx / 2;
  int8_t ystep;

  if (y0 < y1) {
    ystep = 1;
  } else {
    ystep = -1;}

  for (; x0<=x1; x0++) {
    if (steep) {
        ST7565_my_setpixel(y0, x0, color);
    } else {
        ST7565_my_setpixel(x0, y0, color);
    }
    err -= dy;
    if (err < 0) {
      y0 += ystep;
      err += dx;
    }
  }
}

// filled rectangle
void ST7565_fillrect(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t w, uint8_t h, uint8_t color) {
  uint8_t i, j;

  // stupidest version - just pixels - but fast with internal buffer!
  for (i=x; i<x+w; i++) {
    for (j=y; j<y+h; j++) {
      ST7565_my_setpixel(i, j, color);
    }
  }

  ST7565_updateBoundingBox(x, y, x+w, y+h);
}

// draw a rectangle
void ST7565_drawrect(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t w, uint8_t h, uint8_t color) {
  uint8_t i;
  // stupidest version - just pixels - but fast with internal buffer!
  for (i=x; i<x+w; i++) {
    ST7565_my_setpixel(i, y, color);
    ST7565_my_setpixel(i, y+h-1, color);
  }
  for (i=y; i<y+h; i++) {
    ST7565_my_setpixel(x, i, color);
    ST7565_my_setpixel(x+w-1, i, color);
  }

  ST7565_updateBoundingBox(x, y, x+w, y+h);
}

// draw a circle outline
void ST7565_drawcircle(uint8_t x0, uint8_t y0, uint8_t r, uint8_t color) {
    ST7565_updateBoundingBox(x0-r, y0-r, x0+r, y0+r);

  int8_t f = 1 - r;
  int8_t ddF_x = 1;
  int8_t ddF_y = -2 * r;
  int8_t x = 0;
  int8_t y = r;

  ST7565_my_setpixel(x0, y0+r, color);
  ST7565_my_setpixel(x0, y0-r, color);
  ST7565_my_setpixel(x0+r, y0, color);
  ST7565_my_setpixel(x0-r, y0, color);

  while (x<y) {
    if (f >= 0) {
      y--;
      ddF_y += 2;
      f += ddF_y;
    }
    x++;
    ddF_x += 2;
    f += ddF_x;

    ST7565_my_setpixel(x0 + x, y0 + y, color);
    ST7565_my_setpixel(x0 - x, y0 + y, color);
    ST7565_my_setpixel(x0 + x, y0 - y, color);
    ST7565_my_setpixel(x0 - x, y0 - y, color);

    ST7565_my_setpixel(x0 + y, y0 + x, color);
    ST7565_my_setpixel(x0 - y, y0 + x, color);
    ST7565_my_setpixel(x0 + y, y0 - x, color);
    ST7565_my_setpixel(x0 - y, y0 - x, color);

  }



}

void ST7565_fillcircle(uint8_t x0, uint8_t y0, uint8_t r, uint8_t color) {
  ST7565_updateBoundingBox(x0-r, y0-r, x0+r, y0+r);

  int8_t f = 1 - r;
  int8_t ddF_x = 1;
  int8_t ddF_y = -2 * r;
  int8_t x = 0;
  int8_t y = r;
  uint8_t i;

  for (i=y0-r; i<=y0+r; i++) {
    ST7565_my_setpixel(x0, i, color);
  }

  while (x<y) {
    if (f >= 0) {
      y--;
      ddF_y += 2;
      f += ddF_y;
    }
    x++;
    ddF_x += 2;
    f += ddF_x;

    for (i=y0-y; i<=y0+y; i++) {
      ST7565_my_setpixel(x0+x, i, color);
      ST7565_my_setpixel(x0-x, i, color);
    }
    for (i=y0-x; i<=y0+x; i++) {
      ST7565_my_setpixel(x0+y, i, color);
      ST7565_my_setpixel(x0-y, i, color);
    }
  }
}

void ST7565_my_setpixel(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t color) {
  if ((x >= LCDWIDTH) || (y >= LCDHEIGHT))
    return;

  // x is which column
  if (color)
    st7565_buffer[x+ (y/8)*128] |= (1<<(7-(y%8)));
  else
    st7565_buffer[x+ (y/8)*128] &= ~(1<<(7-(y%8)));
}

// the most basic function, set a single pixel
void ST7565_setpixel(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t color) {
  if ((x >= LCDWIDTH) || (y >= LCDHEIGHT))
    return;

  // x is which column
  if (color)
    st7565_buffer[x+ (y/8)*128] |= (1<<(7-(y%8)));
  else
    st7565_buffer[x+ (y/8)*128] &= ~(1<<(7-(y%8)));

  ST7565_updateBoundingBox(x,y,x,y);
}


// the most basic function, get a single pixel
uint8_t ST7565_getpixel(uint8_t x, uint8_t y) {
  if ((x >= LCDWIDTH) || (y >= LCDHEIGHT))
    return 0;

  return (st7565_buffer[x+ (y/8)*128] >> (7-(y%8))) & 0x1;
}

void ST7565_begin(uint8_t contrast) {
  ST7565_st7565_init();
  ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_DISPLAY_ON);
  ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_ALLPTS_NORMAL);
  ST7565_st7565_set_brightness(contrast);
}

void ST7565_st7565_init(void) {

//  toggle RST low to reset; CS is low so it'll listen to us
//  if (cs > 0)
//  digitalWrite(cs, LOW);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // CS LOW

//  digitalWrite(rst, LOW);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // RST LOW 0.5sec

//  wait 0.5sec
  HAL_Delay(500);

//  digitalWrite(rst, HIGH);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET); // RST HIGH

  // LCD bias select
  ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_BIAS_7);
  // ADC select
  ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_ADC_NORMAL);
  // SHL select
  ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_COM_NORMAL);
  // Initial display line
  ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_DISP_START_LINE);

  // turn on voltage converter (VC=1, VR=0, VF=0)
  ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_POWER_CONTROL | 0x4);
  // wait for 50% rising
  HAL_Delay(50);

  // turn on voltage regulator (VC=1, VR=1, VF=0)
  ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_POWER_CONTROL | 0x6);
  // wait >=50ms
  HAL_Delay(50);

  // turn on voltage follower (VC=1, VR=1, VF=1)
  ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_POWER_CONTROL | 0x7);
  // wait
  HAL_Delay(10);

  // set lcd operating voltage (regulator resistor, ref voltage resistor)
  ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_RESISTOR_RATIO | 0x6);

  // initial display line
  // set page address
  // set column address
  // write display data

  // set up a bounding box for screen updates

  ST7565_updateBoundingBox(0, 0, LCDWIDTH-1, LCDHEIGHT-1);
}



inline void ST7565_spiwrite(uint8_t c) {
//shiftOut(sid, sclk, MSBFIRST, c);
//while (SPI_GetFlagStatus(SPI2, SPI_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
//SPI_SendData(SPI2, c);
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, &c, 1, 500);
}

void ST7565_st7565_command(uint8_t c) {
//  digitalWrite(a0, LOW);
// GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_4);
 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  ST7565_spiwrite(c);
}

void ST7565_st7565_data(uint8_t c) {
//  digitalWrite(a0, HIGH);
// GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_11);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  ST7565_spiwrite(c);
}
void ST7565_st7565_set_brightness(uint8_t val) {
    ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_VOLUME_FIRST);
    ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_VOLUME_SECOND | (val & 0x3f));
}


void ST7565_display(void) {
  uint8_t col, maxcol, p;

  /*
  Serial.print("Refresh ("); Serial.print(xUpdateMin, DEC);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.print(xUpdateMax, DEC);
  Serial.print(","); Serial.print(yUpdateMin, DEC);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.print(yUpdateMax, DEC); Serial.println(")");
  */

  for(p = 0; p < 8; p++) {
    /*
      putstring("new page! ");
      uart_putw_dec(p);
      putstring_nl("");
    */
#ifdef enablePartialUpdate
    // check if this page is part of update
    if ( yUpdateMin >= ((p+1)*8) ) {
      continue;   // nope, skip it!
    }
    if (yUpdateMax < p*8) {
      break;
    }
#endif

    HAL_Delay(1);

    ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_PAGE | pagemap[p]);
    HAL_Delay(1);


#ifdef enablePartialUpdate
    col = xUpdateMin;
    maxcol = xUpdateMax;
#else
    // start at the beginning of the row
    col = 0;
    maxcol = LCDWIDTH;
#endif

    ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_COLUMN_LOWER | ((col+ST7565_STARTBYTES) & 0xf));
    HAL_Delay(1);
    ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_COLUMN_UPPER | (((col+ST7565_STARTBYTES) >> 4) & 0x0F));
    HAL_Delay(1);
    ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_RMW);
    HAL_Delay(1);

    for(; col < maxcol; col++) {
      //uart_putw_dec(col);
      //uart_putchar(' ');
      ST7565_st7565_data(st7565_buffer[(128*p)+col]);
      //DelayuS(10);
    }
  }

#ifdef enablePartialUpdate
  xUpdateMin = LCDWIDTH;// - 1;
  xUpdateMax = 0;
  yUpdateMin = LCDHEIGHT;//-1;
  yUpdateMax = 0;
#endif
}

// clear everything
void ST7565_clear(void) {
  memset(st7565_buffer, 0, 1024);
  ST7565_updateBoundingBox(0, 0, LCDWIDTH-1, LCDHEIGHT-1);
}


// this doesnt touch the buffer, just clears the display RAM - might be handy
void ST7565_clear_display(void) {
  uint8_t p, c;

  for(p = 0; p < 8; p++) {
    /*
      put
("new page! ");
      uart_putw_dec(p);
      putstring_nl("");
    */

    ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_PAGE | p);
    for(c = 0; c < 128; c++) {
      //uart_putw_dec(c);
      //uart_putchar(' ');
      ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_COLUMN_LOWER | (c & 0xf));
      ST7565_st7565_command(CMD_SET_COLUMN_UPPER | ((c >> 4) & 0xf));
      //DelayuS(10);
      ST7565_st7565_data(0x0);
    }
  }
}
```

(I'm not an experienced programmer)

I tried to find answers in the forums, and i found it https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/issues/1187.
I cannot adapt the solution to my library. The problem as above matches my 100%